# Comparative after or before the noun

Tags: comparative

I have normally seen people invert the placement of the adjective and put them after the noun when the adjective is a comparative one:

- I have **good** hair - I have hair **better** than his

I would like to know whether it is possible to use the comparative and still place the adjective before the noun:

- I have **better** hair than his

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where there is flexibility in word order, the difference becomes one of emphasis. For example the Subject Verb Object order is strict in English but in other languages where Subject and Object can be distinguished by case, there is greater flexibility in placement, allowing variation for emphasis (e.g. on who did vs to whom).

In your case both are grammatically permissible, so the difference comes down to a bit more weighting on either the hair itself or its relative status. English puts a bit more weight toward what's at front:

> I have *better* hair than him.
>
> I have *hair* better than him.

As such you'll rarely hear the latter, unless someone is really into their hair.

Comment: Some people (myself included) are grammatically uncomfortable with "I have better hair than him."  I would say, "I have better hair than he does."

Answer (score 1):

Everything's fine with the position of the adjective. But "hair", a non-count noun, does not take an article. Hence:

I have good hair.
I have hair better than his.
I have better hair than his/him.

These are all grammatically correct and in everyday use.